# 1:1 Alignment of C# Structs with Streamed Delphi Records Possible?

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

So I have a Delphi application that is taking records of various types, throwing them on a memorystream via `stream.Write(record, sizeof(record))` and sending them over a named pipe.

Take this Delphi record :

```
Type TAboutData = record
  Version : array[0..4] of Byte;
  Build : Word;
  BuildDate : TDateTime;
  SVNChangeset : Word;
end;
```

When this is sent over the named pipe, it comes out like this in a byte[] array :

Length: 22 Bytes

> 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 4 bytes for array
>
> 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 2 bytes for build, 2 bytes for alignment?
>
> 0x15, 0xA3, 0x86, 0x3F, 8 bytes for double
>
> 0xBC, 0x44, 0xE4, 0x40,
>
> 0xA3, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 2 bytes for SVNChangeSet, 2 bytes alignment?
>
> 0x00, 0x00,             2 bytes for something else?

**Alignment Questions**

1. I believe this is called alignment in 4-byte boundries, correct?
2. What are the last two bytes for?

Now I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to marshal this into a C# struct.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct TAboutInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] Version;
        public ushort Build;
        public double BuildDate;
        public ushort SVNChangeSet;
    }    

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytebuffer.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytebuffer, 0, bytebuffer.Length);
    TAboutInfo ta = (TAboutInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TAboutInfo));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

**C# Questions**

1. This simply does not work, and I can't really figure out how to account for the alignment.  I've tried explicit offsets but I'm coming up short.
2. I have many record types, some with members that are dynamic arrays of other records.  I'd rather come up with a robust solution to converting these byte arrays into structures or objects.

Comment: By the way, `array[0..4] of Byte` contains 5 bytes, not 4. What is SizeOf(record) in Delphi? I guess it's 20, not 22.

Comment: SizeOf(TAboutData) in Delphi 2007 and XE4 both give 24, which makes sense with padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alignment is normally used by the compiler as an optimization. Actually every structure is padded to a multiple of 4 (or 8 I don't remember exactly).

**Update**: What I state above about alignment is not accurate. Have a read of David's answer for details on how aligned records are treated by the compiler. The Wikipedia article contains a reasonable overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Anyway, you can use the Pack parameter to specify the alignment. A Pack value of 1 returns the exact size of the structure.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
```

About arrays, it's correct to use:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
public char[] someCharArray;
```

Just take care when you convert from structure to byte array that the array must match the declared size. Before converting, you should use **Array.Resize** if the content is shorter.

```
struct.someCharArray = "Hello".ToCharArray();
Array.Resize<char>(ref struct.someCharArray, 20);
```

About marshaling I use this method from byte[] to structure:

```
    public static T ParseStructure<T>(byte[] array, int offset) where T : struct
    {
        if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array", "Input parameter cannot be null");

        if (array.Length - offset < Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)))
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref array, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) + offset);

        int arraySize = array.Length - offset;
        T returnItem;

        // Allocate some unmanaged memory.
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(arraySize);

        // Copy the read byte array (byte[]) into the unmanaged memory block.
        Marshal.Copy(array, offset, buffer, arraySize);

        // Marshal the unmanaged memory block to a structure.
        returnItem = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(T));

        // Free the unmanaged memory block.
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

        return returnItem;
 }
```

And this method does the opposite:

```
    public static byte[] StructureToArray<T>(T structure) where T : struct
    {
        int objectSize = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
        byte[] result = new byte[objectSize];
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objectSize);

        object dataStructure = (object)structure;

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(dataStructure, buffer, true);

        Marshal.Copy(buffer, result, 0, objectSize);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        return result;
    }
```

Also, please use the following code to check the size calculated by the framework:

```
int objectSize = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
```

Finally I found this nice [article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) about marshalling.

Comment: I swear I was just on the verge of figuring this out when your Oasis of an answer finished the work for me.  THANK YOU MUCH! You're the man!

Comment: No need for Pack=1. You should not do that without a reason. So, why? And you first paragraph is simply incorrect. Check the size of a struct containing a single byte.

Comment: It's good to have the whole picture I agree. But your answer is not it. Start with the first paragraph which is completely incorrect.

Comment: I understand fine and what you say is plain wrong. I explained how and in my answer described alignment. You said *Actually every structure is padded to a multiple of 4 (or 8 I don't remember exactly)* which is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your Delphi compiler is operating in the default mode and so is aligning records. I also assume that your Pascal code contains a simple typo where your array has 5 elements instead of 4.

The alignment of an aligned record is determined by the member with the largest alignment. The largest member is the 8 byte double. So the record has alignment 8. Its size is an exact multiple of its alignment.

Each individual field is aligned to match the field's alignment. The byte array has alignment 1 and can appear anywhere. The 2 byte integers must appear on 2 byte boundaries, and so on. Records may have padding at the end to ensure that arrays of the record will also be aligned. So the record has size that is a multiple of 8. Your record has size 24.

In your case, the padding is before the 8 byte double, and at the end of the record. If this padding at the end was not included, the 8 byte double would be mis-aligned in any arrays of your record.

There's no need to make any changes in your Delphi record and C# struct declarations. They are already declared correctly, and match each other perfectly.

You can use the SizeOf in Delphi and Marshal.SizeOf in C# to check the size of your structures. You will find that they match with the code in the question.

I cannot comment on how your code failed because you did not describe that failure. My main point is that any failure is not because of a mis-match between your structures. There's no rational explanation for the source of the number 22. I'd look to where that number comes from.

Finally, the answer that you accepted proposes using packed structures. There's no need to do that, I see no reason to do so, and it does not explain your problems.

Comment: The size "22" is the length of the packet I'm getting from Delphi.  TAboutData is filled, then sent via TPipeServer.SendStream() [It is not serialized, it is simply read into a stream of bytes].  It looks like it is missing the last two pad-bytes for some reason?

The Delphi application is a closed source app I have no access to.

I should've commented that the Pack parameter was not needed.  I was just excited to have an alternative to StructureToPtr() that was actually working.

Comment: I don't see an alternative. PtrToStructure is it.

Comment: Sorry, "implementation of" not "alternative to"

Comment: The real problem I have with the answer you accepted is the gross factual error in the first paragraph. You asked about alignment and accepted and answer that is utterly wrong on that subject.

Comment: @dna2 the problem is that you don't seem to understand alignment

Comment: David, I'm not here to be schooled, you can simply flag my answer (which I edited 10 times already), which is everything is required here on SO. Regards

Comment: @dna2 Not here to be schooled? Fine. I could teach you no probs, but if you don't want to learn.

Comment: What about you to learn some netiquette? I accept criticism but it took 3/4 messages to get from you what you did considered wrong. It's easy to throw 'it's wrong, it's wrong' or 'the problem is that you don't seem to understand alignment'...it doesn't help me improve the answer... and by the way, you're behaviour is really aggressive. No news I took a defensive stand. I will be pleased to remove my answer, but I simply can't. Do you want me to flag it myself? Will it calm your anger to me?

Comment: Also added "Community wiki", If I understand what it's for, you should now be able to edit it freely.

Comment: @dna2 I don't need community wiki to edit your answer. I have enough rep to edit it. But I don't particularly want to completely re-write the answer. Because then it would look just like mine. And etiquette here demands that you don't re-write accepted answers. Right from the off I explained what's wrong. Not in a comment, but in my answer. I only added my answer to correct the deficiencies of yours. I don't like it if the accepted answer is badly wrong. I'm sure you don't like it either. You seem to me to be very honourable, and I'm really not trying to be aggressive.